# How to Prove the Dimension of the Annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the same question as posted [here](http://goo.gl/4ZZGne) . However I don't understand the proof given.

The question is, for a Vector Space $V$ with a subspace $U$, prove that: $\text{dim} U + \text{dim}U^{0}=\text{dim}V$. Where $U^{0}$ is the annihilator of U.

The proof as given was:

> Assuming you are dealing with finite dimensional spaces, you can just use a dual basis argument: Suppose $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m\}$ is a basis for $U$, which can be extended to a basis $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m, v_{m+1}, \ldots, v_n\}$ for $V$.
>
> Let $\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \ldots, \varphi_n\}$ be a dual basis for $V^{\ast}$, then
>   $$
> \{\varphi_{m+1}, \varphi_{m+2}, \ldots, \varphi_n\} \subset U^{\circ}
> $$
>   Now check that this set forms a basis for $U^{\circ}$.

I understand that: $\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \ldots, \varphi_n\}$ can be assigned as a dual basis for $V^{\ast}$, however I don't understand why that implies that $
\{\varphi_{m+1}, \varphi_{m+2}, \ldots, \varphi_n\} \subset U^{\circ}$.  If you could expand on that, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof: dimension of annihilator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611575/proof-dimension-of-annihilator)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't if my comment would become buried, since the other post is a few months old.

Comment: @user123429 There is no problem is asking this as a question. You linked to the relevant question, but you should make your question self contained, as people shouldn't have to open links to be able to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$\varphi_k(v_j) = 
\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if } k = j\\
  0 & \text{if } k \ne j\text{}
\end{cases}$$

So every element of $\{\varphi_{m+1}, \dots, \varphi_{n}\}$ is zero on each basis element of $U$, hence $\{\varphi_{m+1} , \dots,\varphi_n \} \subseteq U^\circ$.