A trivial problem about two identical hyperplanes
I've been studying Support Vector Machines lately and encountered a trivial problem about hyperplanes.
I use an ordered pair $[w;b]$, where $w\in {\bf R}^n-\{\bf 0\}$ and $b\in \bf R$, to implicitly demonstrate the hyperplane $\{x\in {\bf R}^n\mid w^Tx+b=0\}$.
Clearly, for any nonzero scalar $k$, we have $[w;b]$ and $[kw;kb]$ mapped to the same hyperplane.
My problem is: if $[w_1;b_1]$ and $[w_2;b_2]$ demonstrate the same hyperplane, is there a nonzero scalar $k$ such that $w_2=kw_1$ and $b_2=kb_1$?
If you find my description above confusing, please simply consider and prove the following equivalent proposition:
$$
\forall x\in{\bf R}^n(w_1^Tx=0\leftrightarrow w_2^Tx=0)\to\exists k\neq 0(kw_1=w_2),
$$
where $w_1,w_2\in{\bf R}^n$ and $n\geq 1.$
Much thanks!

Your guess is correct. Suggest you draw some pictures in the plane,  some $Ax + By = C$   and $Dx + Ey = F$   and see when the lines are parallel. All the features of your general problem are present. Oh, and when are two such lines perpendicular?

OP is asking how to get $k$ , @WillJagy , OP has no guesses in regards to calculating $k$ , though that is indeed a very trivial calculation. I have answered at the level of the OP , meanwhile , somebody aware or unaware of the issue took the trivial approach to downvote without commenting , hence I am not sure what changes I have to make in my asnwer.

Are you aware of the geometrical meaning of $w$ and $b$? $w$ is a normal vector to the plane, and if $||w||= 1$, then $b$ is the (signed) distance of the hyperplane to the origin. If you know this the answer to your question should be rather easy to establish.

I am looking for a proof to the formal proposition which I believe to be more direct than my original description to the problem's background. I chose not to take the bias $b$ into account to keep the focus on the normal vector $w$. Thanks for your modification to my post, @Prem, but I intend to keep mine.

@Thomas Thanks for comment! Their geometrical meaning is clear to me, but I am having trouble to reach a formal proof. I was thinking of $N(w_1^T)$, $N(w_2^T)$ and $N([w_1 w_2]^T)$ and their dimensions, but I hope to gather a more concise approach.

One proof would be by https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611575/694754 .  If they weren't scalar multiples, the codimension of the annihilator of the span of ${w_1, w_2}$ would be $2$, not $1$, which is what it would have to be if $w_1$, $w_2$ annihilated the same space.

When $kb_1$ is not necessarily $b_2$ , the Hyper Planes might be Parallel , though not Equivalent & not Identical , which is covered in my answer. You were asking "Is there a Non-Zero $k$ ?" hence I have answered how to know whether that $k$ exists & how to get that $k$ if it exists. Are you asking some thing else ? You should then update the Question.

Your problem has a positive answer. In fact much more is true.
Let $X$ be a real vector space $\not=\{0\}$ with an inner product $\langle~,~\rangle$. Moreover for $0\not=a\in X$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ let
$[a;b]:=H_{a,b}:=\{x\in X\mid \langle a,x\rangle=b\}$. Then (for $0\not=a'\in X $ and $b'\in\mathbb{R}$) it is true that
$[a;b]=[a';b']$ implies that there is some $\lambda\not=0$ such that $a'=\lambda a$ and $b'=\lambda b$.
Proof. Observe that with $\alpha:=\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }$ the vector $x_0:=\alpha a$ is contained in $[a;b]$. Moreover $x_0+x'\in [a;b]$ for all $x'\in [a;0]$. Thus by assumption
$$\langle a',x'+x_0\rangle=b'\quad\quad (*)$$
which in particular is true for $x'=0$: $\langle a',x_0\rangle=b'$. Then $(*)$ implies $b'+\langle a',x'\rangle=b'$ or $\langle a',x'\rangle=0$.
This means that
$$\langle a,x'\rangle=0\Rightarrow \langle a',x'\rangle=0.\quad\quad(\#)$$
Now we show that $a$ and $a'$ are linearly dependent: Obviously $x=\lambda a+a'$ with $\lambda=-\frac{\langle a,a'\rangle}{\langle a,a\rangle}$ satisfies $\langle a,x\rangle=0$. Thus by $(\#)$ $\langle a',x\rangle=0$ which implies
$$\langle a',a'\rangle-\frac{\langle a,a'\rangle^2}{\langle a,a\rangle}=0$$
i.e., $\langle a,a'\rangle^2=\langle a,a\rangle \langle a',a'\rangle$, the case of equality in the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, which only holds true in the case that $a,a'$ are linearly dependent.
So there is some $\lambda\not=0$ such that $a'=\lambda a$. Finally we use
$\langle a,\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=b$ again. This implies $\langle a',\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=b'$ or
$\langle \lambda a,\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=b'$. This implies $b'=\lambda b$ since $\langle \lambda a,\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=\lambda \langle  a,\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=\lambda b$.

Much obliged! Your answer has been of great help and very intuitive. I noticed two minor corrections that could be made to $(#)$ and $\langle \lambda a,\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=b$, which in my opinion would be $\langle a,x'\rangle=0\Rightarrow \langle a',x'\rangle=0$ and $\langle \lambda a,\frac{b}{\langle a,a \rangle }a\rangle=b'$ instead.

You are right. Thank you!
