# Have I shown these linear functionals span the annihilator?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Full exercise.**

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then

$$
\text{dim}\ U^0 = \text{dim}\ V - \text{dim}\ U.
$$

**My Question.**

My strategy is exactly how the first proof in this post goes about showing the above result: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2475382/645756

However, the way they approached showing that the linear functionals span the annihilator $U^0$ is different than my demonstration below.

Let $\varphi \in U^0$. Then for all $u \in U$, we have $\varphi (u) = 0$. Assuming we have already shown $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_{n} \in U^0$, we have that

\begin{align}
\varphi (u) = 0 &= a_{m+1} \cdot 0 + \cdots + a_n \cdot 0 \\
&= a_{m+1} \cdot \varphi_{m+1}(u) + \cdots + a_n \cdot \varphi_{n}(u)
\end{align}

This shows that $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_{n}$ spans $U^0$.

Is this correct?

**EDIT.**

I suspect what I have shown is incorrect. Following the logic I laid out, I can say

\begin{align}
\varphi (u) = 0 = a_{m+1} \cdot 0 
= a_{m+1} \cdot \varphi_{m+1}(u) 
\end{align}

which, by my logic, shows $\varphi_{m+1}$ spans $U^0$. This is obviously wrong. But why does this approach go wrong?

Comment: No. Please justify your final sentence.

Comment: You didn't prove the $\varphi_k$ are linearly independent. All the $\varphi_k$ could be the zero map making it a zero dimensional space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi, sorry. Can you take a look at my EDIT?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Couldn't I prove that after? I would just state that they are part of the linearly independent list $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m, \varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n$ (the dual basis), thus they are linearly independent.

Comment: Give a proof that *any* set of annihilating maps spans $U^0$. You’ve not justified anything.

Comment: @PaulAsh you can't assume they're $U^0$ and assume they're linearly independent at the same time. It makes your reasoning circular.

Comment: @TedShifrin Are you saying to show $span(\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n) = U^0$? Isn't this the same thing as showing that for any element in $U^0$, we can express that element as a linear combination of $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n \in U^0$? Could you explain why that is not what I did?

Comment: @CyclotomicField could you explain why? I can show that they're in $U^0$ first, and then show linear independence, no?

Comment: @PaulAsh you can't assume what you're trying to prove. Assuming there are exactly the right number of linearly independent vectors in $U^0$ is not a proof.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I think we're misunderstanding each other. Let me create an answer that shows what I mean, and if you're willing, we can start a comment chain there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below is in response to my conversation with CyclotomicField.**

Showing $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n \in U^0$.

> Let $V$ be finite-dimensional. Then $U$ must be finite-dimensional.
> Let $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ be a basis of $U$ and extend this basis to a
> basis of $V$:  $$u_1, \ldots, u_m, u_{m+1}, \ldots u_n$$
>
> Thus, we have $\text{dim} \ V = n$, $\text{dim} \ U = m$. We want to
> show $\text{dim} \ U^0 = n - m$.
>
> Consider the dual basis of the basis of $V$ given by the list
> $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m, \varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n$
> where each linear functional is defined by
>
> $$ \varphi_j(u_k) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if} \ k=j, \\ 0, & \text{if} \ k \neq j. \end{cases} $$
>
> Then, for any $u \in U$ and $j = m+1, \ldots, n$
>
> \begin{align} u = a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_mu_m  & \implies \\ \varphi_j(u) = a_1 \varphi_j(u_1) + \cdots + a_m  \varphi_j(u_m) & \implies \\ \varphi_j(u) = a_1 \cdot 0 + \cdots + a_m  \cdot 0 = 0 \end{align}
>
> That is, $\varphi_j(u) = 0$ for all $u \in U$ where $j = m+1, \ldots, n$. This implies  $$\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n \in U^0$$

Showing the list $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n$ is linearly independent.

> Since the dual basis $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_m, \varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n$ is a basis of $V^0$, we have that it is linearly independent. Since any part of a linearly independent list is itself linearly independent, we have that $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n$ is linearly independent.

Showing the list $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n$ spans $U^0$.

> We already have $span(\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n) \subseteq U^0$
> since we showed $\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n \in U^0$ and $U^0$
> is a subspace. We now show $U^0 \subseteq span(\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n)$.
>
> If $\varphi \in U^0$, then $\varphi \in V’$. With the basis of $V’$,
> we have
>
> $$ \varphi = a_1\varphi_1 + \cdots + a_m\varphi_m + a_{m+1}\varphi_{m+1} + \cdots + a_n\varphi_n \tag{1} $$
>
> which implies
>
> $$ \varphi(u_j) = a_j\varphi_j(u_j) = a_j \tag{2} $$
>
> for $j = 1, \ldots, m, m+1, \ldots, n.$ Substituting $\varphi(u_j)$ in $(2)$ for $a_j$ in $(1)$, we have
>
> $$ \varphi = \varphi(u_1)\varphi_1 + \cdots + \varphi(u_m)\varphi_m + \varphi(u_{m+1})\varphi_{m+1} + \cdots + \varphi(u_n)\varphi_n \tag{3}$$
>
> Since $\varphi \in U^0$ and $u_1, \ldots, u_m \in U$, we have $\varphi(u_1) = \cdots = \varphi(u_m) = 0$. Thus, $(3)$ becomes
>
> $$ \varphi = \varphi(u_{m+1})\varphi_{m+1} + \cdots + \varphi(u_n)\varphi_n  $$
>
> implying $\varphi \in span(\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n)$ and so, $U^0 \subseteq span(\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n)$.
>
> Hence, $span(\varphi_{m+1}, \ldots, \varphi_n) = U^0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField please take a look when you can.

Comment: This is far different from your original attempt. Here the $\varphi_i$ are constructed explicitly as elements of a dual basis. What’s still lacking here is a justification that the linear functionals span the annihilator. You’ve shown only that they are linearly independent elements of the annihilator.

Comment: @PaulAsh this better as you've constructed some linear functionals but it's still incomplete. As Ted pointed out you need to show they span $U^0$ to finish it up.

Comment: @CyclotomicField

Thank you. Before I do show the spanning, what if I continued this proof with what I had in my original attempt at showing the spanning. Would it still be incorrect? And if so, why?

Comment: Don’t go down that path. Your original “argument” was a worthless complete handwave. Continue with the structure you have set up here.

Comment: @TedShifrin point taken. I have added my argument for spanning above.

Comment: Is $V^0$ really the notation for the dual vector space? The annihilator of $V$ consists just of the $0$ map. But yes, using the original dual basis gives a correct argument. Is this not how the original proof you linked proceeds?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, used the wrong notation there. The dual space is denoted $V’$. I fixed that in my post. And yes, this is how the proof in the link proceeds, the whole point of my post was asking about my original approach to showing the span.

Comment: OK, your original approach is what I used to tell my students was "proof by intimidation." You just declare it's so with no justification :)